# Modify rows where the column start with certain digits

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep("variable", 9),
                 national_id = rep(-9999, times = 9),
                 state_id = c(rep(-9999, times = 5), 11, 22, 25, -9999),
                 district_id = c(11011, 11201, 22013, 22014, 25016, -9999, -9999, -9999, -9999),
                 d_value = rnorm(9),
                 p_value = rnorm(9))
```

I want to select and add 1 to `d_value` for those rows where the first two digits of `distict_id` is 11.

Similarly I want to add 0.6 (or any number) `d_value` for those rows where the first two digits of `distict_id` is 22.

Also, I want to add 0.6 (or any number) `d_value` for those rows where the first two digits of `district_id` is 22. 
I want to add 0.9 to 'd_value for those rows where 'state_id' is 11.

Comment: Read about `?case_when`

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Sotos I didn't know where to start from actually. I know how to select rows based on column values but not how to select rows based on first two digits of a column

Comment: You can split, use regex or even use math to capture the first two digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a substring (or RegEx) exercise, which base R can handle as well. Create an additional (helper) column with the first 2 digits. Here the substring solution.

```
df$first_2_digits <- substr(x = df$district_id, start = 1, stop = 2)
```

followed by "normal" indexing.

```
df[df$first_2_digits == 11, "d_value"] <- df[df$first_2_digits == 11, "d_value"] + 0.9
```

Easily packagable into a function and extensible with combinations of more than two digits and possibly 'switch' function.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @markus this is a good case for `case_when` where you can have multiple conditions and output for those condition.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(d_value = case_when(str_detect(district_id, "^11") ~ d_value + 1, 
                             str_detect(district_id, "^22") ~ d_value + 0.6, 
                             state_id == 11 ~ d_value + 0.9, 
                             TRUE ~ d_value))
```

We change value of `d_value` based on specified conditions and with `TRUE ~ d_value` we keep `d_value` as it is if none of the above condition is met.